# Fetch linked documents with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose Schema that roughly looks like this:

```
var messageSchema = new Schema({

  answerTo: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Message'
  },

  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }

})
```

**Note:** Sender and receiver are left out for the sake of simplicity.

I would now like to fetch let's say the 10 most recent messages from a conversation. The previous message is linked to in the property `answerTo` — is there any better way than fetching the documents one by one, looping over it until eventually either the limit is reached or `answerTo === null`?

Comment: Why don't you include a datetime field in your schema that denotes when that message was sent/composed so that you can then order the messages to get the most recent ones?

Comment: There is one, even though I have left it out above. The problem is that a user might have multiple conversations at once and I would like to fetch the 10 most recent messages for each conversation. I could just save the messages all in one document, but that might lead to them getting very large. What I want to be able to do is: Start at conversation with id x and fetch the y most recent messages in this conversation.